# When I download a pdf i am getting this error net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from location

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

In my local machine i can download the report successfully. When I copy the jaspers and jrxml file to my production server it is showing this error. Please suggest me.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from location : D:\Ravi Workspace\Openbrm\open-brm-openbrm-2.0\resources\designs\ageing-esr-40-srpski-subreport.jasper
```

In My report I have defined like this and all my jasper files are in the same folder.

```
 <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
 <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Ravi Workspace\\Openbrm\\open-brm-openbrm-2.0\\resources\\designs\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
  </parameter>
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{invoiceInfoList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "ageing-esr-40-srpski-subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

Comment: You should look at [how to pass jasper file path to subreport of subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3702565/876298) post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative path for the Subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360831/relative-path-for-the-subreport)

Answer (score 0):

The path you are using is directly linked to your hard drive. The folder structure for the server will be different.

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387463/5191221 there is no way to use relative paths for the subreport.

So you could either set the path to the exact server path where the subreport lies (I would avoid that at all costs).

Or you could put the subreport into the same folder like the main report and just call it directly:

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["ageing-esr-40-srpski-subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

Comment: Both main report and subreport are in same folder

Comment: Ok, have you tried in changing the expression as provided?

Comment: If you use a repository you should use `<subreportExpression><![CDATA["repo:ageing-esr-40-srpski-subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>`

Comment: Is there is a problem in using the datasource expression instead of connection expression.

Comment: If you provide the data source expression, you are providing the values out of the top records data source to the subreport. When using the connection expression, you only provide the connection (hence the name) and the subreport can select the data on its own. Still, this would not lead to this error that the file cannot be found.

Comment: Please be more specific about your setup in your question. Where do you put the reports? How do the paths look like? Do you have a Jaspersoft Repository running? Do you just use a Java application? What does the error look like if you change the subreportExpression?